# Python Group By Filtering For Specific Rows Based on a Value

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that grouped by certain keys. Now my goal is to select specific rows within each group based on a value for a given column

```py
df_data.groupby([df_data.index, 'symbol']).filter(lambda x: x['Rank'] == 7)
```

I would have expected rows that meet this condition, however I get an error message saying "filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool"

Trying a bit different (after google search) -

```py
df_sql.groupby([df_sql.index, 'symbol']).filter(lambda x: (x['Rank'] == 7).all())
```

I now get Empty DataFrame, while I knows it should not be empty.

Any help with some explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a groupby for something you could just do with `df[df['rank'] == 7]`

Comment: Because I have to group data by 'Symbol', this is commodity data where Symbol is like ['GLD', 'AU', 'SL' etc.] and then select data based on conditions on rank, 7 is an example here in other iterations it could be say Max() of that group. So its just desirable to work on a grouped object, can live without it but preferable to have it